# Customer Address Field Labeled Wrong in Checkout (Magento 2.3 Cloud)

Tags: attributes, magento2.3, customer-attribute

Im having a strange issue , i just created a "Customer Address Attribute" [image] . It is showing correctly on filling **Shipping Address** [image], but when i go to Payment Method it shows me like this [image]. Have any of you have this issue ? Im wondering is this a Magento Bug , because i havent do any override yet to the website .

Comment: Did you created programatically or from admin ? As per my understanding it's a issue with your code of creating attribute.

Comment: I did created from admin

Comment: Set "Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront" to  YES and "Allow HTML Tags on Storefront" to YES in admin for this attribute.

Path : Stores >> Attributes >> Products >> Edit Attribute value and save and check on frontend by clear cache

Comment: You dont get me , this is not a product attribute but a customer attribute

Comment: Are you using enterprise version? Magento don't have option to create customer attribute from admin.

Comment: Im on cloud Enterprice